# input field CSS Code doesn't render correctly when doctype html is added

Tags: php, css, html

I am working on a simple login page with a login form. When i added  `< !DOCTYPE HTML>`, the input field sketched further than the container when set to 100% width. I have searched for solution and noticed questions asked consider doctype messing up css is regarding a specific problem.

Below are my codes;

```css
.loginbox {
  width: 320px;
  height: 440px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 70px 30px;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  .loginbox {
    width: 450px;
    height: 480px;
    padding: 90px 30px;
  }
  .inputContainer input {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
}

.loginavatar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}

.loginbox h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
}

.inputContainer input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #ffffff !important;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.inputContainer input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.logico {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
}

.usernithicon,
.passnithicon {
  position: relative;
}

.inputContainer input[type="text"]:hover,
input[type="password"]:hover,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bc2333;
}

.inputContainer .inputBox label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10%;
  padding: 15px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
}

.inputContainer .inputBox input:focus~label,
.inputContainer .inputBox input:valid~label {
  top: -18px;
  left: 10%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #bc2333;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label {
  display: block;
  margin: 3px 3px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label:before {
  content: "\2714";
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  padding-left: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: transparent;
  transition: .2s;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label:active:before {
  transform: scale(0);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:before {
  background-color: #bc2333;
  border-color: #bc2333;
  color: #fff;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:disabled+label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: #bc2333;
  border-color: #bc2333;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

input[type=checkbox]:disabled+label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  border-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.inputContainer input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  background: #bc2333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: inherit;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}

.inputContainer input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #7a091f;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.inputContainer a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.inputContainer a:hover {
  color: #f4f4f4;
  transition: .2s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="application-name" content="">
  <title>Member Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/FontAwesome/css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/login.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="loginbox">
    <img class="loginavatar" src="assets/images/user.png" draggable="false" />
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <form method="POST" action="">
        <!--<p>Username</p>-->
        <div class="usernithicon inputBox">
          <i class="fa fa-user logico"></i>
          <input type="text" id="usern" name="username" required><label for="usern">Username</label></div>
        <!--<p>Password</p>-->
        <div class="passnithicon inputBox">
          <i class="fa fa-lock logico"></i>
          <input type="password" id="pswrd" name="password" required><label for="pswrd">Password</label></div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="remberme" name="remember"><label for="remberme">Remeber Me</label>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
        <a href="#">Forgot password?</a><br>
        <a href="#">Create An Account</a>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When this renders in browser the username and password input field will become stretched and i was able to use `width:90%;`, which works fine but i would love to have it set to `width:100%;` (which works perfectly without added the doctype tag) but when the doctype code is added, it becomes stretched.

Additional Issue: The background image i added to the body wont cover the whole screen, it breaks in the middle and repeat. i tried adding `background-repeat:none;` but didn't work. but if i remove the doctype tag, the background fills up the page as expected.

How do i solve this?

Comment: your issue is that you didn't add the doctype initially ... now what you have is what you need to have, simply correct it .. read this : https://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Comment: I'm More confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base on what you want i added `display: inline-flex;` in your input wrappers

Try this

```
.loginbox {
  width: 320px;
  height: 440px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 70px 30px;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  .loginbox {
    width: 450px;
    height: 480px;
    padding: 90px 30px;
  }
  .inputContainer input {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
}

.loginavatar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}

.loginbox h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
}

.inputContainer input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #ffffff !important;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.inputContainer input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.logico {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
}

.usernithicon,
.passnithicon {
      position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    width: 100%;
}

.inputContainer input[type="text"]:hover,
input[type="password"]:hover,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bc2333;
}

.inputContainer .inputBox label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10%;
  padding: 15px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
}

.inputContainer .inputBox input:focus~label,
.inputContainer .inputBox input:valid~label {
  top: -22px;
  left: 10%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #bc2333;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label {
  display: block;
  margin: 3px 3px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label:before {
  content: "\2714";
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  padding-left: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: transparent;
  transition: .2s;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label:active:before {
  transform: scale(0);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:before {
  background-color: #bc2333;
  border-color: #bc2333;
  color: #fff;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:disabled+label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: #bc2333;
  border-color: #bc2333;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

input[type=checkbox]:disabled+label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  border-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.inputContainer input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  background: #bc2333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: inherit;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}

.inputContainer input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #7a091f;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.inputContainer a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.inputContainer a:hover {
  color: #f4f4f4;
  transition: .2s ease;
}
```

For the background try this

```
body, html{
   height: 100%; 
   background-image: url('your_image_path')
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Worked but there is another issue, the text cursor now writes under the font icon added [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HP-9l5pHyc5sihMiW0W7_NiQPrHJv6Bf/view )[/link]. The padded was to push the text forward so that the icon an sit in the field. As well as the background image i added, it doesn't render perfectly. How can i solve that?

Comment: That worked like charm. Please @john-velasquez how do i go about the background as seen the the shared video. I set the the `background-size:cover` but still not taking the full height of the page. (works fine without the doctype but with the doctype it shows like that (i mean as i have it in the video screencast))

Comment: Thank you very much @john-velasquez, Everything looks good now. :)

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: Please up this answer, if this answers your question thanks :)